# Is using Java applet makes the page to load slower?

Tags: java, browser, applet

```
package javaapplication3;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;

/*<applet code="NewApplet" width="3000" height="80">
<param name="fontName" value="Courrier"></applet>*/
public class NewApplet extends Applet{
    int c,d;

    public void start(){
      c=9;d=8;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
      g.drawString("Muliplication"+c*d,0,10);
    }
}
```

I have read many advantages/disadvantages of Java applet in many sites, but still I want to know some things:

1. Is it necessary for a user to have JDK and JRE installed on his/her system to run applet on web browser?
2. Will this program makes the browser to download these two packages (`java.applet.Applet`,`java.awt.*`)?
3. Is using Applet good or bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Only the JRE
2. No, they are included in the JRE
3. Bad, Java applets aren't a recommended web technology anymore and probably many of your users will not see them properly. Java applets should be reserved for some special applications and probably Intranet only.

Most stuff that was done in Java applets can now be written "Web 2.0-style" with HTML5, Javascript, Ajax etc. without requiring any plug-ins.

Comment: What that applet is doing (displaying the result of a multiplication) could be done in HTML/JS.  To paint it at a custom location (perhaps 'bouncing around inside a container') could also be done using HTML/JS, though the HTML 5 `canvas` would make it easier (and probably more reliable). +1

Answer (score 1):

1. JRE not JDK
2. Check this out because it seems you have not understood the concept of java packages
   en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package
3. Read this:
   http://www.ehow.com/info_12152621_advantages-disadvantages-using-java-applets.html